# Connecting parallel to Li-po

Tags: arduino, power-supply, lipo

I think I have pretty newbie question but I couldn't find specific answer for that.

I have 7.4 V li-po pack. What I want to do is connect in parallel two dc loads. One will be motor drive which will be supplied with regulated voltage 6 V second will be Arduino supplied with 7.4 V.

Is it correct and safe to do such circuit with li-po pack?

Below I'm uploading how circuit would look like
[image]

Comment: The devil is in the interconnections between Arduino and the motor but otherwise, yes.

Comment: Do you suggest that connecting motors and Arduino in one circuit can damage Arduino somehow? Can I protect board , or It's better to power them separately?

Comment: I'm not going to speculate without some kind of firm proposal from you about what interconnections you require. Maybe a block diagram is needed.

Comment: Just uploaded simple schematic, please comment on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important under circumstances like this (where there may be several amps flowing through the 0 volts feed), to star-point your 0 volts at the motor controller: -

[image]

This will be the first step to minimize data corruptions between arduino and driver controller. That star-point (the big green blob) is "officially" your 0 volts reference point.

But, of course, there will be currents flowing through the 0 volt connection to your arduino that *could* create small volt drops down its 0 volt feed. Those small volt drops will superimpose themselves on the driver control signals BUT the level will be small and normally tolerable.

If in the process of possible expansion of your design, sensors are attached that might bypass the star point system, you have to avoid this. If the sensors are all teed-off from the arduino then this is unlikely.